# Is there a way to use cvar via say command?

Tags: dota-2

I am experimenting with Cvars.

Those are variables set in the server and or client.

List here: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/List_of_DOTA_2_Cvars

I want to export some of those via the say command but i am missing the syntax to do so.

For example:

`say "My Hostport is :%s" %hostport`

and

`say "My Hostport is :" +hostport`

does not work.

If there is a way with autoexec i would love to use that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console in Source engine is very, very limited, and even more so in Dota 2.

The only 2 things you can do with a *cvar* are: print it to console and overwrite it.

What you want to do is impossible.

Comment: well thats sad. my intention was to get the current gametime ,(optional) add 10 min and say in allychat "roshan died at, respawns at: x". thx for your clear answer. i will let this question stay unaccepted for 2 days. maybe someone has a solution.